# Looking for JavaScript 3d ploting library

Tags: javascript, plot

Is there any JavaScript 3d ploting library so I can do draw plot like that:

```
  plotingObject = new plotingLib.fromCanvas(canvas);
  var data = [[1,2,3], [2,2,3]];
  plotingObject.plot(data);
```

I found only whole 3d engines, or 3d bars :( But I need something simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried [3D Surface Plotting in JavaScript](https://code.google.com/p/javascript-surface-plot/) .I think it might help you.